# Signification de l'expression "Je demeure"

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Si quelqu'un peut m'éclaircir sur la signification de "Je demeure" que je l'ai trouvé a la fin des lettres de l'épistolaire *Les Pauvres Gens* de Dostoïevski, traduction Marc Chapiro (1845).

Exemples :

> .... connaître votre dernier mot. Dans cette attente, je demeure.

> ....,ma tourterelle, Quant à moi, je demeurerai toujours.

> ...., et que le Seigneur soit avec vous. Pour moi, je demeure.

Dans quel contexte, pourrais-je utiliser la même expression?
Je serais reconnaissant à tous ceux qui consacreront du temps pour répondre à ma question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Demeurer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/demeurer)* signifie ici *rester, continuer à être*.

Les phrases en question sont tronquées. Il faut lire :

> *Dans cette attente, **je demeure votre dévouée**.*

> *Quant à moi, **je demeurerai toujours votre ami le plus fidèle**.*

> *[...], et que le Seigneur soit avec vous. Pour moi, **je demeure votre ami fidèle**.*

L'édition française a une mise en page étrange de ces phrase. Voici par exemple la première :

[image]

Elle s'explique quand on la compare avec celle de l'original en russe :

[image]

On y retrouve *В ожидании пребываю* (je suis en attente, je demeure) séparé de la fin de la phrase, *вас любящая*, par un saut de ligne et une indentation marquée.

Answer (score 2):

Un autre exemple célèbre:

> Vienne la nuit sonne l'heure
>
> Les jours s'en vont je demeure

Comment: Très célèbre en effet, mais j'ajouterais quand même que l'utilisation de *demeurer* sans complément comme le fait ici Apollinaire est assez exceptionnelle.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, tu as sans doute raison. Mais c'est inoubliable, c'est le premier exemple qui m'est venu à l'esprit :-)